# A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and no address was supplied

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets

I have read all posts with this problem here on Stackoverflow but none solved my problem.
I have created authentication class for client-server app I am building that uses TCP sockets:

```
public class Authentication
{
private Socket _socket;
private AddressFamily _addressFamily;
private SocketType _socketType;
private ProtocolType _protocolType;
private IPAddress _ipAddress;
private IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint;

private bool _running = true;

public Authentication(SocketType socketType, AddressFamily family, ProtocolType protocolType)
{
    _addressFamily = family;
    _socketType = socketType;
    _protocolType = protocolType;
}

public int Connect(string ipAdd, int port)
{
    try
    {
        _addressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork;
        _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdd);
        _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, port);
        _socket = new Socket(_addressFamily, _socketType, _protocolType);
        _socket.Connect(_ipEndPoint);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
public int Listen(string ipAdd, int port, ClientManager clientManager)
{
    try
    {
        _ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdd);
        _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_ipAddress, port);
        _socket = new Socket(_addressFamily, _socketType, _protocolType);
        _socket.Bind(_ipEndPoint);
        while (_running)
        {
            _socket.Listen(30000);
            Socket socket = _socket.Accept();

            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                ConnectionAccepted(ref socket, clientManager);
            });
            thread.Start();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

private void ConnectionAccepted(ref Socket socket, ClientManager clientManager)
{
    try
    {
        string command = "";
        do
        {
            byte[] len = new byte[4];
            socket.Receive(len); //receive length of command
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(len, 0)];
            socket.Receive(buffer);
            command = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
            if (command.Contains("LOGIN"))
                LoginServerSide(ref socket, clientManager);
            else if (command.Contains("REGISTER"))
                RegisterServerSide(socket, clientManager); 
        } while (!command.Contains("TERMINATE"));
        Close(socket);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

public bool LoginClientSide(string username, string password)
 {
     if (_socket == null)
         return false;
     //send action
     byte[] login = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("LOGIN");
     _socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(login.Length));
     _socket.Send(login);
     byte[] ok = new byte[4];
     _socket.Receive(ok);
     if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok) == "OK")
     {
         //send username
         byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(username);
         _socket.Send(usernameBytes);
         ok = new byte[40];
         _socket.Receive(ok); //OK: salt_value
         if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok).Split(':').First() == "OK")
         {
             //get salt
             byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok).Split(':').Last());
             //send hashed password
             byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
             byte[] hashedPassword = CreateHashedPassword(passwordBytes, saltBytes);
             _socket.Send(hashedPassword);
             _socket.Receive(ok);
             if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok) == "OK")
                 return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

 private void LoginServerSide(ref Socket socket, ClientManager clientManager)
 {
     byte[] ok = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("OK");
     byte[] err = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ER");
     //response to action
     _socket.Send(ok);
     //receive username
     byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
     socket.Receive(buffer);
     string username = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
     //check for existing user
     if (clientManager.CheckForUser(username))
     {
         //user exists send OK: salt_value
         byte[] salt = clientManager.GetSalt(username);
         socket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("OK: " + salt));
         //receive hashed password
         buffer = new byte[64];
         socket.Receive(buffer);
         byte[] hashedPassword = clientManager.GetHashedPassword(username);
         if (buffer.SequenceEqual(hashedPassword))
         {
             //password is ok
             socket.Send(ok);
         }
         socket.Send(err);
     }
     //user does not exist
     socket.Send(err);
 }

public KeyValuePair<byte[], long> RegisterClientSide(string username, string password)
{
    if (_socket == null)
        throw new Exception("Socket not initialized");
    byte[] register = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("REGISTER");
    _socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(register.Length));
    _socket.Send(register);
    byte[] ok = new byte[4];
    _socket.Receive(ok);
    string tmp = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok);
    if (tmp == "OK")
    {
        //send username
        byte[] usernameBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(username);
        _socket.Send(usernameBytes);
        ok = new byte[4];
        _socket.Receive(ok);
        if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok) == "OK")
        {
            //generate and send salt
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            rng.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
            _socket.Send(salt);
            _socket.Receive(ok);
            if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok) == "OK")
            {
                //send hashed password
                byte[] passwordBytes = CreateHashedPassword(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password), salt);
                _socket.Send(passwordBytes);
                _socket.Receive(ok);
                if (Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ok).Split(':').First() == "OK")
                {
                    byte[] idBytes = new byte[8];
                    _socket.Receive(idBytes);
                    long id = BitConverter.ToInt64(idBytes, 0);
                    //created new user
                    return new KeyValuePair<byte[], long>(salt, id);
                }
                //server error
            }
            //server error
        }
        //username exists
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<byte[], long>();
}

private void RegisterServerSide(Socket socket, ClientManager clientManager)
{
    byte[] ok = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("OK");
    byte[] err = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("ER");
    //response to action
    socket.Send(ok);
    //receive username
    byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
    socket.Receive(buffer);
    string username = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer).TrimEnd('\0');
    //check for existing user
    if (!clientManager.CheckForUser(username))
    {
        //user does not exist send ok
        socket.Send(ok);
        //receive salt
        buffer = new byte[16];
        socket.Receive(buffer);
        //save salt
        byte[] salt = new byte[16];
        buffer.CopyTo(salt, 0);
        //send ok
        socket.Send(ok);
        //receive hashed password
        buffer = new byte[64];
        socket.Receive(buffer);
        //save hashed password
        byte[] pass = new byte[64];
        buffer.CopyTo(pass, 0);
        //send ok: id
        long id = clientManager.CreateNewUser(username, pass, salt);
        socket.Send(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("OK"));
        socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(id));
    }
    else
        socket.Send(err);
}
}
```

Now in WPF application I used this class for registration and it worked just fine but when it comes to login it breaks when server tries to send "OK" and gives me error I put in the title of this article.
This is how it is done on client side for register:

```
Authentication _auth = new Authentication(SocketType.Stream, AddressFamily.InterNetwork, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_auth.Connect(_serverIPAdd, _port);
KeyValuePair<byte[], long> info = _auth.RegisterClientSide(reg.Username.Text, reg.Password.Text);
```

and for login:

```
Authentication _auth = new Authentication(SocketType.Stream, AddressFamily.InterNetwork, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_auth.Connect(_serverIPAdd, _port);
bool login = _auth.LoginClientSide(login.textBox.Text, login.textBox1.Text)
```

On the server side:

```
Authentication _auth = new Authentication(SocketType.Stream, AddressFamily.InterNetwork, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_auth.Listen(_IPAddress, _port, this);
```

So from this you can see that I did the same procedure for connecting client to server but in one case this passes and in other(login) it fails. 
IP address is my local IP and port is 30012.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Why are you not checking for the failed result from `Connect()`? You should be checking if it returns -1. In fact, you're better off just dealing with the exception because -1 tells you nothing about why it failed to connect. Also, why are you setting `_addressFamily` in `Connect()` when you already set it in the constructor? You're totally ignoring the argument you passed into the constructor by doing this.

Comment: @itsme86 setting _addressFamily in Connect() is from old version of my code that i forgot to delete. In any case I am using InterNetwork. Regarding exceptions I just shortened code for this article. I am catching every possible exception and for now it gives me only mentioned one.

Comment: why is this question tagged with [tag:wpf], when there is only socket-related code ... ??

Answer (score 0):

I have found where my mistake was. In LoginServerSide function on first sending of "OK" i used listening socked (*_socket*) instead of working socket created on accept (*socket*).